# How to maintain separate folders for datasource, middleware and config in Loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

When I created a project in **Loopback** using `lb` command I got below folder structure.

```
D:.
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   
+---client
|       README.md
|       
+---common
|   \---models
|           division.js
|           division.json
|           users-profiles.js
|           users-profiles.json
|           
\---server
    |   component-config.json
    |   config.json
    |   datasources.json
    |   datasources.production.json
    |   middleware.development.json
    |   middleware.json
    |   model-config.json
    |   server.js
    |   
    \---boot
            authentication.js
            root.js
```

But I want to maintain separate folder structure for `datasource, middleware and config` files in loopback.

For Example:

```
D:.
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   
+---client
|       README.md
|       
+---common
|   \---models
|           division.js
|           division.json
|           users-profiles.js
|           users-profiles.json
|           
\---server
    |   component-config.json
    |   config.json
    |   middleware.development.json
    |   middleware.json
    |   model-config.json
    |   server.js
    |   
    +---boot
    |       authentication.js
    |       root.js
    |       
    \---**datasources**
            datasources.json
            datasources.production.json
```

Once I tried to do this, i.e trying to place datasources in separate folder I got below error in Loopback.

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: MySql is referencing a dataSource that does not exist:
```

Is there any other way to resolve this? So, I can able to manage my folder structure in Loopback.